# Calling Task from Gradle(Kotlin) function

Tags: function, gradle, kotlin, task

I want to create a single build.gradle, in where i have multiple EntryPoints(Task's), that all publish a different artifact to my Artifactory.

Since i want to cut down repeating code i though this would work:

```
fun push(fileToUpload: File, pubName: String)
{
    publishing {
            publications {
                create<MavenPublication>(pubName) {
                    artifact(fileToUpload)
                }
            }
            repositories {
                maven {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
}
```

But how do i actually run **this** configured publishing Task?
(I just started working with gradle so, so dont hate me too much.)